# how to set selected Text bold?

Tags: android

I want to set a selected text in an `EditText` bold.

It's already possible to find out what characters I selected and with `getSelectionStart() and getSelectionEnd( )` I know where's the position.

But my problem is, that I want to set the selected Text bold with a Button and don't know how to set the font bold with a String (I only know how to set it with `EditText`).

So here is my sample code:

```
    fettdruckButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int selectionStart = fullscreenEdittext.getSelectionStart();
            int selectionEnd = fullscreenEdittext.getSelectionEnd();

            int differenz = selectionEnd - selectionStart;

            String selectedText = fullscreenEdittext.getText().toString().substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
            Log.d("selectedText", "selectedText " + selectedText + "|" + selectionStart + "|" + selectionEnd);


            //fullscreenEdittext.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        }
    });
```

Comment: u want it after the button click or while selecting the text

Comment: after the button click the selected text shall appears bold

Answer (score 1):

Use SpannableStringBuilder.

```
SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = (SpannableStringBuilder) fullscreeneditText.getText();
stringBuilder.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), selectionStart, selectionEnd, 0);
```

Please note that if you want to do this many times you should remove your original span first.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property of `Editext` `fullscreenEdittext.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));`
Use html formatting tags `<b>selectedText</b>`  to make the selected text bold.
Please have a look at below code snippet

```
int selectionStart = fullscreenEdittext.getSelectionStart();
    int selectionEnd = fullscreenEdittext.getSelectionEnd();

    String startingText = fullscreenEdittext.getText().toString()
            .substring(0, selectionStart);
    String selectedText = fullscreenEdittext.getText().toString()
            .substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    String endingText = fullscreenEdittext.getText().toString()
            .substring(selectionEnd);

    fullscreenEdittext.setText(Html.fromHtml(startingText + "<b>"
            + selectedText + "</b>" + endingText));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String completetext=fullscreenEdittext.getText().toString();
int selectionStart = fullscreenEdittext.getSelectionStart();
int selectionEnd = fullscreenEdittext.getSelectionEnd();
int differenz = selectionEnd - selectionStart;
String selectedText = fullscreenEdittext.getText().toString().substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
Log.d("selectedText", "selectedText " + selectedText + "|" + selectionStart + "|" + selectionEnd);

String part1=fullscreenEdittext.getText().toString().substring(0, selectionStart);

String part2=fullscreenEdittext.getText().toString().substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);

String part3=fullscreenEdittext.getText().toString().substring(selectionEnd,completetext.length() );

fullscreenEdittext.setText(Html.fromHtml(part1+"<b>" + part2+ "</b>" +part3));
```